# Missing { inserted within matplotlib2tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, matplotlib, matplotlib2tikz

After using matplotlib to create a bar chart, I use matplotlib2tikz to create a tikz figure. The code is as following:

```
% This file was created by matplotlib2tikz v0.6.13.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.75,0,0.75}

\begin{axis}[
title={Gender distribution},
xlabel={Age},
ylabel={Number of people},
xmin=-0.22, xmax=2.42,
ymin=0, ymax=10.5,
xtick={0.1,1.1,2.1},
xticklabels={{14-19},{20-27},{28-35}},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black},
y grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black},
legend style={draw=white!80.0!black},
legend entries={{Male},{Female}},
legend cell align={left}
]
\draw[fill=blue,draw opacity=0] (axis cs:-0.1,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.1,6);
\draw[fill=blue,draw opacity=0] (axis cs:0.9,0) rectangle (axis cs:1.1,3);
\draw[fill=blue,draw opacity=0] (axis cs:1.9,0) rectangle (axis cs:2.1,7);
\draw[fill=color0,draw opacity=0] (axis cs:0.1,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.3,4);
\draw[fill=color0,draw opacity=0] (axis cs:1.1,0) rectangle (axis cs:1.3,10);
\draw[fill=color0,draw opacity=0] (axis cs:2.1,0) rectangle (axis cs:2.3,6);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the log file, I get the error

```
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!

./test.tex:28: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.28 \end{axis}
```

followed by

```
./test.tex:28: Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28 \end{axis}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

./test.tex:28: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpgfpicture ...globally \endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                      \pgf@restore@layerlist@fro...
l.28 \end{axis}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: I got a problem with `\begin{axis}`.

Comment: There are `legend entries`set -  without any `\addplot` commands. Remove the `legend entries` from the `axis` settings or add `ybar` to the `axis` options and `\addlegendimage{ybar legend,fill=blue,draw opacity=0}` and `\addlegendimage{ybar legend,fill=color0,draw opacity=0}` inside the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was building the code @esdd already gave the correct answer, you have to apply \addplot to use \legend entries. Here you go

```
\documentclass [tikz] {standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.75,0,0.75}

\begin{axis}[
ybar,
bar width=15pt,
xlabel = Age,
ylabel = Number of people,
xmin=-0.22, xmax=2.42,
ymin=0, ymax=10.5,
xtick={0.1,1.1,2.1},
xticklabels={{14-19},{20-27},{28-35}},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black},
y grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black},
enlargelimits=false,
legend style={draw=white!80.0!black},
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={Male, Female},
]

\addplot[fill=blue,draw opacity=0] coordinates {(0.1,6) (1.1,3) (2.1,7)};    
\addplot[fill=color0,draw opacity=0] coordinates {(0.1,4) (1.1,10) (2.1,6)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```